# Looping multiple TukeyHSD tests into one table?

Tags: r, loops, anova, tukey

I have multiple csv files similar to the following.

```
Library Parameter1
A       3
A       2
A       5
B       2
B       1
B       9
C       4
C       2
C       8
```

It actually looks like this: [CSV Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao2a7.png)

Each .csv file is named after a chemical parameter such as "logtPSA.csv" in this case. The headers as you can tell are "Library" and "Value". I have 4 different libraries: FDA, SMMRNA, VD_SM, and VD_MV.

I have been performing ANOVA tests and TukeyHSD tests for all of them but R doesn't give it in a format where the results are separated into cells so I can just copy and paste into Excel therefore if I were to do it by hand it would get quite tedious.

I was wondering if there was some way I could write a function that would go through all of my files one at a time, perform the test, and output it all into two neat tables (1 for ANOVA, 1 for TukeyHSD).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing this, this is just one:

## Import all data files

```
setwd("C:/Users/VANBE/Desktop")
files = dir(".", pattern = ".csv")
files.dir = paste(getwd(),"/" ,files,sep="")
load = lapply(files.dir, read.csv2,header=T,sep=",",dec=".")
names(load)=unlist(strsplit(files,".csv")) # not truly necesary
```

## An example of how it might look

```
load = list(FILENAME1=data.frame(x=1699:1722,Library=c(rep("FDA",18),rep("SMMRMA",6)),logtPSA=rnorm(1.5,1,24)),
            FILENAME2=data.frame(x=1699:1722,Library=c(rep("FDA",18),rep("SMMRMA",6)),logtELSE=rnorm(2,1,24)))
```

## Put results into a dataframe

```
load= lapply(load, function(x) {names(x) = c("number","library","parameter");  return(x) }) # make sure columnnames of al items are identical

f.AN = function(x){out=aov(parameter ~ library,x)
AN=summary(out)[[1]]}
f.TU = function(x){out=aov(parameter ~ library,x)
TU=TukeyHSD(out)[[1]]}

AN = do.call("rbind",lapply(load,f.AN))
TU = do.call("rbind",lapply(load,f.TU))
```

Comment: Hi Wave thank you for answering. I got as far as the first section of your answer before I couldn't figure out how to substitute things to make it work for me specifically. I updated my question with more specific info so I was hoping you could help me out a bit more? I can, of course, provide whatever additional information is necessary. I'm still very new to R so I wasn't sure if I was naming all my files and headers in a reasonable and efficient manner. Thank you!